# directive to controller multiple function calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have one angular js code in with I have created directive with two functions, now I want to call controller function and pass values from directive functions, but one function is working another is not, here is code

```
return {
    scope: {
        someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn',
        filterRecords: '&searchResult'
    },
    templateUrl:'public/js/app/directives/views/filter.directive.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //this function calling to controller function
        scope.callme = function(){
            scope.someCtrlFn();
        };

        //this function not calling function to controller function
        scope.filterData = function (query) {
            scope.filterRecords(query);
        }
    }
}
```

here is html code

```
<side-filter 
 callback-Fn="ctrl.toggleFilterMenu();"
 search-result="ctrl.compilationParams(params);">
</side-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
<side-filter callback-Fn="ctrl.toggleFilterMenu" 
     search-result="ctrl.compilationParams">
     </side-filter>
```

This passes a reference to the functions, instead of executing the functions on load.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, in this sample you can call actions from controller in the directive, see what's the different with your codes.

> Directive template has 2 buttons `test` call `$scope.toggleFilterMenu`
>   function from controller will return **"console from controller"** and `test2` call
>   `$scope.compilationParams` function from controller with param will
>   return **"console from directive"** from directive.

**update**

We also create `listener` service to set and get between controller and directive this will help you to get param and use them in directive with promise.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, listener) {
  $scope.toggleFilterMenu = function() {
    console.log("console from controller")
  }

  $scope.compilationParams = function(param) {
    listener.set(param)
  }
})

app.service("listener", function($rootScope, $q) {
  this.set = function(param) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('param', param);
  }

  this.get = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.$on('param', function(ev, params) {
       deferred.resolve(params);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
})

app.directive("sideFilter", function(listener) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn',
      filterRecords: '&searchResult'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="callme()">test</button> <button ng-click="filterData()">test2</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //this function calling to controller function
      scope.callme = function() {
        scope.someCtrlFn();
      };

      //this function not calling function to controller function
      scope.filterData = function() {
        listener.get().then(function(response) {
          console.log('console from directive',response)
        })
        scope.filterRecords();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <side-filter callback-Fn="toggleFilterMenu();" search-result="compilationParams('123');">
  </side-filter>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Maher thanks for answer but on second method I am not getting parameters coming from directives I am getting undefined params on controller function

Comment: hi @kalpeshR, you can use service to `set` and `get` i update the answer, i hope helps you